# Google motion chart from dynamic csv file

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am trying to make a web page that displays a google chart when a button is clicked. Heres the code so far

```html
<cfheader name="X-XSS-Protection" value="0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function Chart(){
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["motionchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
        data.addRows([
          ['Apples',  new Date (1988,0,1), 1000, 300, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1988,0,1), 1150, 200, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1988,0,1), 300,  250, 'West'],
          ['Apples',  new Date (1989,6,1), 1200, 400, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1989,6,1), 750,  150, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1989,6,1), 788,  617, 'West']
        ]);
        var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height:300});
      }
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <content style="float: left;">  
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></div>
 </content>
 <input type="button" value="Chart" onclick="Chart()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

The chart is displayed without the added code, but with the code, when the button is pressed the page goes blank and and my  tags are empty.
P.S New to html/javascript

Comment: Try making your button call drawChart() instead of wrapping the standard code in another function. The Google API loader only needs to run once, and I'm not sure if it triggers the callback function if run again.

Comment: As another note, by convention in JavaScript all function names begin with a lowercase letter.  Functions beginning with uppercase letters are constructors used to build an object of a certain type.